# How can I get all my subscribed channel using youtube api v3

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I'm new to youtube api v3, and I have a problem when get all my subscribed channel. I've subscribed 65 channel but I can only get 50 each api call. So, Is there any way to get all?

Another thing is, I have a channelID, is there any api to check this channel in a list of my subscribed channel?

Comment: how did you get subscribed channel list ? can you post some logic here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youtube API restricts 50 results per call. In case you were asking whether you can get all 65 in the same call, then the answer is no. However, if you meant whether all 65 can be retrieved then, yes. You'll need to use the nextPageToken paramter value and pass it to the pageToken parameter which will take you to the next page. In code, it can be handled in the following way(as shown in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list)):

```
var nextPageToken = '';

    // This loop retrieves a set of playlist items and checks the nextPageToken 
    // in the response to determine whether the list contains additional items. 
    // It repeats that process until it has retrieved all of the items in the list.

    while (nextPageToken != null) {
      var playlistResponse = YouTube.PlaylistItems.list('snippet', {
        playlistId: playlistId,
        maxResults: 25,
        pageToken: nextPageToken
      });
```

Regarding your ChannelID problem, from your description I understand you want to check whether you are subscribed to a particular channel in case you have it's ID. I believe the [Activities](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities) method of Youtube API should be able to help you out. Look at contentDetails.subscription property. I hope that resolves your problem.

Comment: Actually I found the answer but anyway thanks for your answer :)
So, I wanna ask another question. I heard that you can only retrieve last 2 weeks of history playlist. Is that true? I don't know how to check that